# UnboundLocalError after try import from a optional dependency

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

Below is a minimal code to regenerate error

```
def foo(): 
    # hard code implementation
    pass

def func(): 
    try:
        from scipy import foo # unsuccess here
    except: 
        ...

    foo()

func()
```

Error

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'foo' referenced before assignment
```

**My motivation**:

Basically, here I'm trying to call this `foo()` function. I notice `scipy` might already implement it. Since scipy is so heavy so I would like to avoid make `scipy` as the dependency. However. if user occasionally has scipy installed already, I would like to import method from scipy and use it. If user doesn't, that's fine. I hard code function `foo` for you already.

**Question**:
Why `UnboundLocalError` is triggered? Is there something under the hood of `import`?

Here `foo` and `scipy` are just examples to make sure import unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merely having the `import` statement in `func` (whether it succeeds or not) is enough for the code generator to make `foo` a local name. (An `import` statement is a kind of fancy assignment statement). As a result, it won't fall back to the global variable of the same name, even if no variable by that name is defined.

To allow `foo` to continue to work if the `import` fails, declare `foo` as global.

```
def foo(): 
    # hard code implementation
    pass

def func(): 
    global foo
    try:
        from scipy import foo # unsuccess here
    except: 
        ...

    foo()

func()
```

---

You can observe the difference by putting your code in a file `tmp.py`, and running `python -mdis tmp.py`, with and without the `global` statement. Without `global`, you'll see the use of `STORE_NAME`, `STORE_FAST`, and `LOAD_FAST`, as the decision to use a local variable must be made before the code can actually execute.

Comment: Thanks. I guess `*_FAST` means local? Then, why python built-in `locals()` doesn't show `foo` in without global case? Another question: `-mdis` looks cool, where could I find it's document or explaination?

Comment: `locals` only shows the variables that are actually defined. Whether a name belongs to a scope is separate from whether a variable by that names exists. `dis` is just a module in the standard library; `-m` is an option used to run a module as a script.